# How to consolidate springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException stack trace?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

This stack trace is long and confusing. It lists 5 causes: UnsatisfiedDependencyException / BeanCreationException / UnsatisfiedDependencyException / BeanCreationException / Actual error (NoHostname).

Is there any way to reduce this to a single cause?

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'vtMonitorController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'service': Error creating bean with name 'messageHistoryService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'repo': Error creating bean with name 'tsMessageHistoryRepo': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'cassandraTemplate' while setting bean property 'cassandraTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'cassandraTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/cassandra/CassandraDataAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'cassandraTemplate' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'session' defined in class path resource [com/vz/ts/vt/db/config/CassandraConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /127.0.0.1:9043 (com.datastax.driver.core.TransportException: [/127.0.0.1:9043] Cannot connect)); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'session' defined in class path resource [com/vz/ts/vt/db/config/CassandraConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /127.0.0.1:9043 (com.datastax.driver.core.TransportException: [/127.0.0.1:9043] Cannot connect)); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tsMessageHistoryRepo': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'cassandraTemplate' while setting bean property 'cassandraTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'cassandraTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/cassandra/CassandraDataAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'cassandraTemplate' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'session' defined in class path resource [com/vz/ts/vt/db/config/CassandraConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /127.0.0.1:9043 (com.datastax.driver.core.TransportException: [/127.0.0.1:9043] Cannot connect)); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'session' defined in class path resource [com/vz/ts/vt/db/config/CassandraConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /127.0.0.1:9043 (com.datastax.driver.core.TransportException: [/127.0.0.1:9043] Cannot connect)); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'messageHistoryService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'repo': Error creating bean with name 'tsMessageHistoryRepo': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'cassandraTemplate' while setting bean property 'cassandraTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'cassandraTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/cassandra/CassandraDataAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'cassandraTemplate' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'session' defined in class path resource [com/vz/ts/vt/db/config/CassandraConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /127.0.0.1:9043 (com.datastax.driver.core.TransportException: [/127.0.0.1:9043] Cannot connect)); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'session' defined in class path resource [com/vz/ts/vt/db/config/CassandraConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /127.0.0.1:9043 (com.datastax.driver.core.TransportException: [/127.0.0.1:9043] Cannot connect)); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tsMessageHistoryRepo': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'cassandraTemplate' while setting bean property 'cassandraTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'cassandraTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/cassandra/CassandraDataAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'cassandraTemplate' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'session' defined in class path resource [com/vz/ts/vt/db/config/CassandraConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /127.0.0.1:9043 (com.datastax.driver.core.TransportException: [/127.0.0.1:9043] Cannot connect)); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'session' defined in class path resource [com/vz/ts/vt/db/config/CassandraConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /127.0.0.1:9043 (com.datastax.driver.core.TransportException: [/127.0.0.1:9043] Cannot connect))
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:350)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:774)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:841)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:540)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:773)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:368)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1190)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1179)
    at com.vz.ts.vt.monitor.rs.Application.main(Application.java:15)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'messageHistoryService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'repo': Error creating bean with name 'tsMessageHistoryRepo': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'cassandraTemplate' while setting bean property 'cassandraTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'cassandraTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/cassandra/CassandraDataAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'cassandraTemplate' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'session' defined in class path resource [com/vz/ts/vt/db/config/CassandraConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /127.0.0.1:9043 (com.datastax.driver.core.TransportException: [/127.0.0.1:9043] Cannot connect)); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'session' defined in class path resource [com/vz/ts/vt/db/config/CassandraConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /127.0.0.1:9043 (com.datastax.driver.core.TransportException: [/127.0.0.1:9043] Cannot connect)); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tsMessageHistoryRepo': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'cassandraTemplate' while setting bean property 'cassandraTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'cassandraTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/cassandra/CassandraDataAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'cassandraTemplate' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'session' defined in class path resource [com/vz/ts/vt/db/config/CassandraConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /127.0.0.1:9043 (com.datastax.driver.core.TransportException: [/127.0.0.1:9043] Cannot connect)); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'session' defined in class path resource [com/vz/ts/vt/db/config/CassandraConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /127.0.0.1:9043 (com.datastax.driver.core.TransportException: [/127.0.0.1:9043] Cannot connect))
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:350)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:186)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1201)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1045)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1017)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:570)
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tsMessageHistoryRepo': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'cassandraTemplate' while setting bean property 'cassandraTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'cassandraTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/cassandra/CassandraDataAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'cassandraTemplate' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'session' defined in class path resource [com/vz/ts/vt/db/config/CassandraConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /127.0.0.1:9043 (com.datastax.driver.core.TransportException: [/127.0.0.1:9043] Cannot connect)); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'session' defined in class path resource [com/vz/ts/vt/db/config/CassandraConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /127.0.0.1:9043 (com.datastax.driver.core.TransportException: [/127.0.0.1:9043] Cannot connect))
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1481)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:186)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1201)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1045)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1017)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:570)
    ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'cassandraTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/cassandra/CassandraDataAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'cassandraTemplate' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'session' defined in class path resource [com/vz/ts/vt/db/config/CassandraConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /127.0.0.1:9043 (com.datastax.driver.core.TransportException: [/127.0.0.1:9043] Cannot connect)); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'session' defined in class path resource [com/vz/ts/vt/db/config/CassandraConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /127.0.0.1:9043 (com.datastax.driver.core.TransportException: [/127.0.0.1:9043] Cannot connect))
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:745)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:463)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
    ... 47 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'session' defined in class path resource [com/vz/ts/vt/db/config/CassandraConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /127.0.0.1:9043 (com.datastax.driver.core.TransportException: [/127.0.0.1:9043] Cannot connect))
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:186)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1201)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1045)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1017)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:823)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:737)
    ... 57 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed
```

Comment: There is a single cause.... The stack trace basically includes all the information about the beans it failed to create... Generally the last element is the most interesting one (as that is the root cause).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you know, spring works by Depenedency Injection. Each exception clause reported in your logs entirely different with each other but one dependent on another as per Dependency Injection rule.

BeanCreationException and UnsatisfiedDependencyException is the subclass of java.lang.Runtime Exception. We can't handle Runtime exception gracefully.

Exception works by Stack datastructure algorithm. The last entry usually be the cause of failure, and rest others lying on the top of the actual failure.

- **BeanCreationException** - 'Session' bean wasnt created due to host cant
  be found.
- **UnsatisfiedDependencyException** - 'cassandraTemplate' due to 'session'
  bean wasn't created (Due to First point).
- **BeanCreationException** - 'tsMessageHistoryRepo' due to
  'cassandraTemplate' refernce wasn't found (Due to Second Point).
- **UnsatisfiedDependencyException** - 'messageHistoryService' bean wasnt
  created due to 'cassandraTemplate' & 'Session' bean creation failure
  (Due to First & Second Point).

Comment: Can you please explain why we can't handle this Runtime exception differently? I'm free to make any changes necessary in the code. That's the crux of my question.

Comment: try{...}catch{RuntimeException){..} can handle all runtime exception. 
Capture and give a meaning full text in the log, will resolve mostly. 
But I would say, catch the 'com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException' and throw off processing further, would stop all the remaining exception for this instance. 
All other components is dependent on this one in Dependency Injection flow. 
If you get this 'NoHostAvailableException' any time in future, will stop you create further bean dependent on this.